# Find a file/folder within another folder with OSX UI

Tags: macos, spotlight, quicksilver, alfred

I often have project folders `clientA`, `clientB`, `personalproj1` etc
and often they all have commonly used files/filers e.g. They might all have `myCode.js`, so when I type `myReusedCode.js` in spotlight (or alfred) it will return every file. I REALLY want to be able to type something like this (into Alfred)`find clientB myCode.js` to get THAT instance of `myCode.js`

I realise its possible via *terminal* - but I really wanna do this via finder as most of my "next steps" invovle the UI. I'd like to do it via Alfred if at all possible, i really like that app.

Any ideas/product recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this with “quicksilver”…

In Quicksilver, assuming all the project folders are in your catalog (which is easy to accomplish), you could type something like `ca/mc↩` to open `clientA/myCode.js`.

Specifically, create a custom catalog entry that scans the parent folder containing your projects, or if they’re spread all over the place, you could tag them and add them to the catalog based on that, or list their paths in a file and scan that, or… There are a few options. :-)

Once they’re in the catalog, you can type the entire folder name (like `clientA`) if you hate yourself, but really, just type the first thing that comes to mind as fast as you can think it and Quicksilver will find it (like `clta` or `ca`). After doing this one or two times, it will become the top result.

With any folder selected, you can hit `/` or `→` to get at its contents. (For this reason, it’s unnecessary to have your catalog entries scan deep into the contents, but that’s an option if you want.)

Comment: Ok, that sounds about right. I'll install Quicksilver and have a go